# Very slow join query on large table (machine = Xeon 2.4 GHz, 16 core, 64 GB RAM)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, performance

Here is my query :

```
SELECT  email_data.id, email_data.source_file, email_data.report_id,
        email_data.filePath, email_data.fileName, email_data.size,
        email_data.emailID, email_data.msgID, email_data.cus, email_data.subject,
        email_data.sentto, email_data.emailFrom, email_data.hdrs, email_data.cc,
        email_data.bcc, email_data.extracted, email_data.DateTime,
        email_data.TimeStamp, email_data.OriginalDateTime, email_data.ParentID,
        email_data.reply_to, email_data.MD5Hash, email_data.duplicated,
        email_data.TimeZone, email_data.AttachName, email_data.fqdn, 
        attach_data.id, attach_data.source_file, attach_data.report_id,
        attach_data.filePath, attach_data.fileName, attach_data.size, attach_data.ext,
        attach_data.emailID, attach_data.cus, attach_data.extracted,
        attach_data.MD5Hash, attach_data.duplicated
FROM email_data 
LEFT JOIN attach_data
ON (email_data.emailID = attach_data.emailID);
```

Combination of both of the table has 50k + records (email_data have 22k records and other have 30K + records).

Above query takes over 90 mins and still not finished.

This one :

```
SELECT email_data.id, attach_data.id 
FROM email_data 
LEFT JOIN attach_data 
ON (email_data.emailID = attach_data.emailID);
```

takes 2 mins 22 sec:

What am I doing wrong? It seems that MySQL do not using enough memory to speed things up, and it only uses 1 core out of 16 cores.

How can I configure it to use all available resources?

Or should I query IDs (as in 2nd query) and loop + select each of them back in my code? Will it cause same result?

I needs all those fields and all the row, I am converting them into Custom CSV-Like format so it can be exported to other software.

Columns :

```
mysql> show columns from email_data;
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| source_file      | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| report_id        | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| filePath         | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fileName         | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| size             | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| emailID          | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| msgID            | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cus              | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| subject          | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sentto           | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| emailFrom        | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hdrs             | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cc               | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bcc              | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| extracted        | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DateTime         | char(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TimeStamp        | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| OriginalDateTime | char(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ParentID         | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reply_to         | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| MD5Hash          | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| duplicated       | char(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TimeZone         | char(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AttachName       | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fqdn             | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Almost same for attach_data

Comment: My guess is that you're pulling the actual attachments off the disk (I'm assuming that's attach_data.source_file) and that's slowing everything down. Can you try without the actual attachment? Also, a where clause to restrict to the current email account or current email ID would seem sensible.

Comment: attach_data.source_file is only file name , but i store extracted text of attachment in attach_data.extracted. "Also, a where clause to restrict to the current email account or current email ID would seem sensible" , in my case i need everyrow in the table coz i need to convert them into a file archive that exportable to other software.

Comment: 50k+ records isn't large by most standards...   The sluggishness could be, in part explained by the mere _volume_ of data to be returned, but there's something else astray:  the 2nd query with 2+ minutes is slow too.  Do you have the proper indexes on these tables.  `Have you tried EXPLAIN` ?

Comment: Yeah it seems it is not setup well for this machine.I am not sure , i am not an expert in configuring mysql for that machine yet. EXPLAIN means a tool ? Or should i put my Mysql setting here?

Comment: What mjv says.  50K records shouldn't have noticeable performance issues. My guess is the database schema. In my experience, most SQL performance issues in production environments are a result of a poorly defined DB schema.

Comment: EXPLAIN <query> is a tool that will give you insights into how your query is processed by the query analyzer.  It's used to optimize queries, generally by showing you where you ought to add indexes or modify your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost certain that `attach_data.emailID` is lacking an index.  Consider that the query engine must go through every single row of email data, and if the index is missing, it must walk every row of attach_data, even after finding a match.

You should run an `EXPLAIN` on your query to see what MySql is actually doing.  If the index is missing, you will be doin 22,000 x 30,000 comparisons, or about 660 million comparisons to build up your resulting dataset.  If your id's are strings, you are in for a long ride.

If you do index `attach_data.emailId`, you will reduce the number of comparisons to about 22,000 x log(30,000), or about 330 thousand comparisons.  Huge difference.  Using a `HASH` index will make this even quicker (the lower bound is 22,000 comparisons).  If the indexes are missing, you can attach them after the fact.

And honestly, you should consider `LIMIT` to skip over and take a window of results.  This will save you a lot of grief shuffling that data to and from the client.  You might find that this sort of traffic can cause timeouts on a slow connect (and I agree with another poster, it's strange that you aren't timing out)

**UPDATE**

Holy cow.  Seeing your update to the question, you should definitely pull back only the non-longtext fields, iterate through those and pull back the longtext fields one at a time.  But seeing as your need is to dump a mysql table to a csv, I would recommend looking into [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).  It can back your database up to CSV files for you.

Comment: I can't use CSV coz it is not importable to CSV file , i had written my own converter using all avaliable Data.

Comment: If for whatever reason you can't use the CSV provided by mysqldump, then make sure the indexes are in place and retrieve the longtext fields, one at a time, on a second pass, so that you can actually get some feedback that things are working.

Comment: Good SO create index and select IDs first (like in 2nd query) , loop through each IDs and do select on them? Would be able to put progress bar. Currently Customer believe it freezed due to long operation.

Comment: With the index, you should find that your first response will come back pretty quickly.  When you go back to grab your longstrings, increment the progress bar.  Since you already have the short form results, you should be able to come up with a very close percentage complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i created index and the query went very fast! within 30 sec its done!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you did to have a query to run 90mins and *not* timeout...

Check the field you are joining on.  Specifically, take a look at the execution plan for the query (or estimated execution plan) to see what's the most costly operation.

Are you joining on fields that are varchar(255). varchar(max) or similar?  Comparing large varchars is an expensive operation.  If you can shortern the field that would help.

Regarding all those fields:

Return a smaller subset of fields.  If you are recalling actual attachment data from the sql server, then you may want to first perform a query to identify just which attachments (attach_data.PrimaryKey) are needed, instead of the entire row (which must then be pulled into memory).
Then, once you have the PKs of the required attach_data records, you can recall only the data needed for those rows

Are you joining on non-indexed fields (as in you're *not* joining on a primary key)? Adding indexes to the columns will speed retrieval the process, but learn about indexes before doing so (For example, adding indexes to a column will actually slow data updates/inserts and indexes on int fields are better than indexes on large-range varchars).

Comment: Not just varchar , i am using longtext :( Chaning to Varchar would speed up? and enable index?

Comment: ah, first took your question for MSSQL before you updated, then I realized you using MySQL. But no, varchar vs longtext still long text fields = lots of work sql must do for a join.
Indexing would def help (don't just create, learn about indexing first), but you need to discover the bottleneck. Reduce the fields returned on the join.  I don't know what fields you need in attach_data, but try first identifying what records in attach_data you need (like, just identify the primary keys of attach_data you need, not the data itself) *then* recall those records from attach_data.

Comment: That make sense. I will only need attach_data.id and i can select it back in the code. Wouldn't that speed things up?

Comment: it would indeed, reduce the amount of work to the sql server. Only return what you need etc.

Comment: but that again will cuse multiple select coz i need all those field in every column. Currently i added indexes and it working much better but in future i will need different solution. Data will grow quickly into 10 million of records easily as the application is email and documents analysis system.

Comment: Let me give an example: I have a table with lots of records. One of the fields is varbinary(MAX), which holds data for an actual file (between 300K and 2MB). If I SELECT * FROM TABLE, then varbinary(MAX) field is returned too.
If I select everything *except* the varbinary field, the query is much faster; not returning +- 500K for each row. So with the 'stub' record, I can JOIN and work out which ones I really need. Then I SELECT only those records, varBinary field included.
So yes, it took 2 selects, but I returned a fraction of the data. Think of it as optimizing your retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confusing the optimizer. Try adding an index for `attach_data.emailID`. You can use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) statement to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thx . i do not know that statement before.

Answer (score 1):

First, a single query will never use multiple cores (AFAIK mysql and most other RDBMS).

Your second query shows mysql is able to use an index (or utilize a big cache), that's good.

If your disk is slow and the longtexts contain much data, just pulling all of it to memory may be slow and trash your in memory index pages.

If it is a serious app I would switch to PostgreSQL or another DB as a long term solution. In my experience mysql is only fast for trivial tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. For Long term ,  i am thinking about splitting query into multiple range and processing them concurrenly would make it much faster? Should i go that way?  IS PGSQL better in this case?

Comment: Maybe splitting would help. But only if disk I/O and page memory is not your true problem, else this will make it worse. And of course splitting could complicate index usage. It's hard to predict if and by how much PostgreSQL would improve this, it won't make your disk faster by magic, but it might be smarter in regard to page caching and query planning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation , this makes  alot of sense. Yes disk are just 7500RPM disks planning to replace with 15Ks soon. And Raid array will do good.

Answer (score 0):

You really want all of the rows out of the table?  It would be much better if you could go with smaller queries for what you need at a specific moment in a process.  Ideally you would add a where clause somewhere.  The true lag behind is probably with reading it from the hard drive.  Doing RAID setups with recursive backups might possibly speed this up somehow, but I'm not sure.

You can change some MySQL settings and tell it the max amount of memory to use per query along with some other options.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Comment: Yes i needs all the row , i am converting them into Custom CSV like format so it can be exported to other software.

Comment: Memory storage engine so if i restarted server i lose everything??

Comment: Would not a where clause result in a selection/joining of all rows *before* the sql server returns a subset thereof? Even if you structure the query to take subsets from the two tables and join on those, there's still an underlying schema problem.

Comment: @MoSlo: No, RDMBs are made to optimize this problem specifically. An SQL query only describes the query logically, it is the RDBMS's job to find the best execution plan for it. Having an index will help it find a better execution plan in this case.

Comment: @Jürgen Strobel: I agree that RDBMSes will compose the best execution plan with the schema available. But if *no* indexes exist, will an RDBMS still optimize with just a WHERE clause?  (My comment's intention was to assert that "use where clause" isn't enough when there's a joining issue)

Comment: @MoSlo: Of course an index is very beneficial here. But there are optimizations possible without indices. For example it could read enough from each table to satisfy where-clause checking, not everything selected (especially not big columns stored out of page). It could also read in the joined column of a table first and build a fast hash table in memory.

Comment: @Jürgen Strobel: worth knowing!